# Nifi GenerateFlowFile with Attribute Parameter

Tags: parameters, attributes, apache-nifi, flowfile

is it possible to generate a FlowFile with Attribute Parameters, which get filled on a UpdateAttribute Processor or EvaluateJsonPath Processor?

For Example I have a FlowFile Content:

```
<ImportDocument>
    <Database>${database}</Database>
    <DocumentType>${documentType}</DocumentType>
    <DocumentTitle>${documentTitle}</DocumentTitle>
</ImportDocument>
```

from InvokeHTTP Response I recieve the following response:

```
{ 
    "database" : "abc",
    "documentType" : "RG",
    "documentTitle" : "test"
}
```

Now I want to fill the Parameters from the first FlowFile with the Attribute Values from the HTTP Response, so that the FlowFile Content will be like:

```
<ImportDocument>
    <Database>abc</Database>
    <DocumentType>RG</DocumentType>
    <DocumentTitle>test</DocumentTitle>
</ImportDocument>
```

when I set the Attributes in the Processor EvaluateJsonPath from the HTTP Response

```
database = $.database
documentType = $.documentType
documentTitle = $.documentTitle
```

the Parameters in the FlowFile dont get filled with the values.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: it's not possible without script. however after evaluatejsonpath you can use ReplaceText to replace whole file content with template-like xml body with placeholders (like you have in question)